# How to shrink ibd files with BLOB fields?

Tags: mysql, null, blob, shrink

I have a big table with BLOB fields that contain many NULL values. I enabled Multiple Tablespaces and got a separate ibd file for each table. The physical size of this table is much more than the size I calculate myself, so my conclusion is that it should be possible to shrink this ibd file, but I am still not able to do this, even after reloading a dump file. I verified the dump file really contains SQL statements that inserts NULL values.
Any tips to shrink physical size of this table? Or is this impossible because MySQL allocates a fixed size for blobs?

Comment: I thought I already tried to set the ROW_FORMAT to COMPACT and did not work, but now it is working. Both the Antelope and Barracuda file format shrink the file:  ALTER TABLE DOC ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;  but even if I just say:  ALTER TABLE DOC ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: You have obviously tried OPTIMIZE TABLE after your Multiple Tablespaces were enabled? You may also need to delete files manually when re-importing from SQL dump.

Comment: According to [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html), MySQL should not be allocating a fixed amount of disk for your variable-length column.  Post the data from SHOW TABLE STATUS.

Answer (score 0):

Drop indexes if any on BLOB columns
Please provide o/p of `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '<table_name>'`